# "to be" vs. "being" after adjective (and why)

Tags: difference, gerunds, infinitives, infinitive-vs-gerund

Which sentence is correct, and why?

1) It's awesome **being** by the water.

2) It's awesome **to be** by the water.

Comment: Both could be, depending on context. "being" is more in the moment. "to be" is more about a non-current or desired situation.

Comment: It's possible to answer this question about *awesome*, but it's not really possible to answer generally about "after adjectives".  Different adjectives are different.

Answer (score 6):

Both usages are equally correct. In both examples, you are using a verb (*being*, *to be*) in place of a noun.

In the first case, you are using the gerund form of the verb, and in the second, you are using the infinitive. The gerund is the more common usage in American English, and is easily identified in most cases by a verb with the *-ing* ending.

[Here is a link to a page from Capital Community College that explains this kind of construction in more detail.](http://grammar.ccc.commnet.edu/grammar/gerunds.htm)

Idomatically, as @user3169 pointed out, *being* is used more often in the moment, and *to be* is used more in the abstract. So use *being* when you are actually standing on the beach, right next to the water, and *to be* when you are talking about that situation in general.

Comment: "use being when you are actually standing by the beach... and to be when you're talking about that situation in general."  At the risk of confounding the OP, what about the conflation and reversal of the two forms i.e., "It's awesome to be *here* by the water."  versus "It's awesome being by the water *in summer*." No, the OP didn't ask about these two specifically, but I think it's highly interesting how merely one or two words can throw things fully around...

Comment: oh, and +1 for the great link - very useful site!

Comment: Sure thing, @Howard! I feel like when you specify the time or place, like "here by the water" or "by the water in summer", the implied temporal/positional difference between *being* and *to be* disappears, and is replaced by the time or place that you specified.